# How to set read only form fields in different content types

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, content-type, read-only, sharepoint-fields

I have a list with 4 content types and a workflow. The workflows allows to register and proceed the "new idea"" 
1 step - Registration 
2 step - Categorization 
3 step - Operation 
4 step - Finalization

In each step, assigned user must fill a form and should be able to see the fields from previous step but only as a display/read only fields.

I am looking for a solution to set form filed to read only in different content types. 
I can use mainly OOTB tools and javascript/jslink (but I am not a developer). I cant use Nintex or InfoPath.

Thanks for all help

Comment: is its sharepoint online? if so you should be using powerapps as stated in my answer otherwise it should be SPD. Using javascript can be very messy if you dont know programming!

Answer (score 1):

Considering you wont be using nintex or infopath and have limited knowledge in programming (mainly JavaScript).....

I would say that you use SharePoint Designer as your last resort. What you can do in nintex you can do in SPD but takes a little work and not everything is laid in front of you :) , You can create multiple forms and set them to read only. On each stage have specific fields set to read only. on the workflow just point the url to the specified page.

otherwise if your using sharepoint online i would highly recommend that you use powerapps which can create an applike application all in one to display all custom views. :) its a little learning curve but many articles and howto's to using it. What your asking is quite simple in powerapps with little if any programming knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you can use Nintex, use it (you can do it easily).
Create one form for each content Types. In the form desiner, when you open property of your field, in Advence section, you can set the control mode of your field. So set the control mode of your field to : Display. And when the form is open in edit, your field will be in Read Only.</s>

If you want to use only JS, there is a simple Lib [SPutility JS](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility) to do this, but you need to "dev" it

Hope this help you

Comment: he said he "cant" use nintex and that he has minimal JS knowledge which would make it difficult!

Comment: Hooo... really sorry. I misread....

Comment: lol thats fine :)